Error 404 Not Found when trying to log out
I have a logout form, this goes to the route in web.php, in the controller I have a logout method there is a code to move to the home page, but the error 404 not found appears
public function logout()
{
    Auth::logout();

    request()->session()->invalidate();

    request()->session()->regenerateToken();

    return redirect('/');
}

Route::get('/', [PostController::class, 'home']);

<form action="post" action="/logout">
    @csrf
    <button class="dropdown-item" type="submit">
        <i class="bi bi-box-arrow-right"></i> Logout
    </button>
</form>

I tried php artisan cache:clear but it still has an error, I hope someone can help me

Please show the rest of your web routes file, do you have a route for /logout?

Your have to provide more details, What is Route::get('/', [PostController::class, 'home']); for?! How did you define /logout route?
